# How to disable fancybox on small screens

Tags: mobile

I'm using the plugin "Fancybox for Wordpress" in WP 3.5.1. On small screens, I want to disable the fancybox-script. So, at top of header-file, I include a check for user agent, and sets global variable `$is_mobile` `true` or `false`. This works.

However, depending on this, I would like to add something like this to `functions.php` to disable the script on mobile devices.

```
$is_mobile;
function is_mobile() {
if ($is_mobile==true) {
    remove_action('wp_print_scripts', 'mfbfw_load');
    remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'mfbfw_css');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'mfbfw_init');

} else {$is_mobile = "false"; }

return $is_mobile;
}

add_action('wp_head', 'is_mobile', 1);
```

This doesn't work, maybe because `functions.php` is loaded before `header.php`.
However, it also doesn't work if I include the check for useragent into the function.

Anyway, the variable `$is_mobile` is not recognized as a global in `header.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a try with [`wp_is_mobile()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile):

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
  remove_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'mfbfw_load' );
  remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'mfbfw_css' );
  remove_action( 'wp_head', 'mfbfw_init' );
}
```

You should also check with tablets since they might have a big resolution and hence not fall in your "small screen" condition. You should note that the User Agent string can be modified by any browser sending the request.

Answer (score -1):

Directly under that script try:

$is_mobile = is_mobile();

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?